# Calculate shooter's distance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acoustics, projectile

Let's say a bullet of a 50 bmg with a speed of `4000 ft/sec = 1219.2 m/s` lands right next to you.
About 1 second later, you hear the sound of the shooting.
The speed of sound in dry air at 20 °C = `343 m/s`.
Knowing these facts, what is the distance of the shooter from you?

This is not a homework exercise, just something I thought and need some help because at the moment, I do not know any classical mechanics.

Comment: *This is not a homework exercise.* Whether a question is considered homework-like here has nothing to do with whether it was actually assigned to you as homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sound wave and the bullet are initiated at the same place at the same time ($x=0,t=0$). The sound wave moves as described by $x(t)=v_s t$ (the position is the speed times time). The bullet as described by $x(t)=v_bt$. You sit at a position $x_0$. The bullet lands near you (hopefully only *near*) at a time $x_0/v_b$. Then the sound hits you at a later time $x_0/v_s$. The difference, which you measure as $T$, is $T=x_0/v_s-x_0/v_b$, so $x_0$, the distance you want, is
$$
x_0=\frac{T}{\frac{1}{v_s}-\frac{1}{v_b}}
$$
Which for 1s is 541m.
P.S. I can see that google's "answer" says .50 BMG goes at 4000ft/s, but it's wrong. It's 3000ft/s=915m/s